# IOS - I want to recycle the server data on Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, server, uipageviewcontroller

When we move the a segue from A view to B view or from b view to A view, viewdidload get data from server all the time

So, can we keep the data that viewdidload get at first excute, without starting viewdidload each page?

It's waste of time to get data all the time, when we open each page.

From now we using pageviewcontroller, I think it is inappropriate it.

I using swift language.

If you have good idea, please let me know.

Comment: Look at Model-View-Controller structure (or similar).  Create a Model object to manage and share data.  The controllers can ask the model for data when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are very many tutorials on the internet that show how to do what you want.  Try a google search on `swift pass data between view controllers`.

At its very simplest, the second controller needs to have one or properties that can hold data from the first controller.  The first controller must implement the following function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerClass
    // Pass data to the second view controller.
    secondVC.dataFromServer = dataFromServer
    secondVC.otherData      = otherData  // etc.
}
```

The data will then be passed from the first controller to the second.